# Looping through nested objects and display data

Tags: angular, object, typescript

Still not clear on how to display or iterate through object object. Here is my object:

```
Row{
id: 1,
    widget:{
       name: 'bla bla',
       location:{
             top: 255, right: 0, bottom :0, left: 0;
       }
    }
    location:{
       top: 255, right: 0, bottom :0, left: 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the HTML

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of canvas; let r = index" >
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: row.location.top;">
        ROW {{row}}  {{ row.location | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to put the `row.location.top` that I have in the object in the style inline. For the `row.location | JSON` output I get:

[image]

but if I do `{{ row.location.top | json}}` I get empty.

Comment: Why not just `[ngStyle]="row.location"` in your element?

Comment: i could and that is a great suggestion but also tired of messing around object and would like to learn how to display data as I would need to display only 1 property.

Comment: I tried  [ngStyle]="row.location" and I got output 
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="row" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">

Comment: OK, that's what's supposed to happen. Note that you'd need e.g. `"255px"` not `255` for the style to be valid.

Comment: I guess location is an array as per the dev tool snapshot. Can you please try row.location[0].top and check if you get the correct result?

Comment: row.location[0].top output the data , but if I want to do inline CSS how should I do it? It thought [style.padding]="row.location[0].top row.location[0].right row.location[0].bottom row.location[0].left" should work but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the below image, it looks like location is also an array with only one object in it. So, you can try accessing the top property with array[0] i.e.
 row.location[0].top. This should work I think. 
[image]

Comment: row.location[0].top output the data , but if I want to do inline CSS how should I do it? It thought [style.padding]="row.location[0].top row.location[0].right row.location[0].bottom row.location[0].left" should work but nothing.

Comment: Please refer to this for example( Ignore the formatting of the below code, as no formatting is allowed in comments): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngStyle

Comment: currentStyles: {};
setCurrentStyles() {
  // CSS styles: set per current state of component properties
  this.currentStyles = {
    'font-style':  this.canSave      ? 'italic' : 'normal',
    'font-weight': !this.isUnchanged ? 'bold'   : 'normal',
    'font-size':   this.isSpecial    ? '24px'   : '12px'
  };
}

<div [ngStyle]="currentStyles">
  This div is initially italic, normal weight, and extra large (24px).
</div>